# Can I deploy the Django Rest Framework project on Firebase?

Tags: django, firebase, django-rest-framework, hosting, backend

We are developing an application using Vue.js and Django. The essence of the application: accept user requests from the form, send them for approval to the backend and send an answer to the frontend. On the localhost everything is already organized and working. Now our frontend is on firebase and I want to deploy my backend part somewhere. So, can I use firebase for deploying my part? Вecause I met different ambiguous answers to this question

Comment: Firebase is suited for those that doesn't develop the backend-side, if you're using Django, then deploy on a linux machine or other managed vps servers like heroku or DigitalOcean, or AWS if you want dedicated ones.

Comment: So for the backend, should I use a heroku? Thank you

Comment: it is never only one option, heroku is one of the many options, maybe you should explore and find the best suited one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant, I guess you are using Django Rest Framework with Vue.js. So you need deploy your back-end to some machine. You can choose any hosting which can propose you Linux machine. GoogleCloud, DigitalOcean, AWS, Heroku and a lot of others..

I like AWS (In your case as a new user you can run free EC2 for 12-month, if you do not need a lot of performance)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use Heroku